# C++ printf("%s" , string) is giving me very strange output

Tags: c++, string, file, printf

I am trying to use printf to give my strings color with something like

```
printf("\x1B[92m%d\033[0m", value1);
```

which works for me with integers no problem, but when I try to do something like

```
printf("\x1B[92m%s\033[0m", wantedString);
```

I get random things like, (°√, any help pls?

Here is the whole function

```
void searchFileFor(path const& files, string wantedString) {
    
    ifstream inFile;
    string currentString;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    bool foundNothing = true;

    for (auto file : recursive_directory_iterator(files)) {
        lineNumber = 0; // Reset after each new file
        inFile.open(file);
        while (inFile >> currentString) {
            lineNumber++;
            if (currentString.find(wantedString) != string::npos) {
                cout << file << " " << wantedString << " " << lineNumber << '\n';
                foundNothing = false;
            }
            //cout << file << " " <<  currentString << endl;
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    if (foundNothing == true) {
        cout << "We were not able to find: " << wantedString << "";
        printf("\x1B[92m%s\033[0m", wantedString);
    }
    //cout << "Wanted String: " << wantedString;
}
```

Comment: What is in `wantedString`?

Comment: You probably need `wantedString.c_str()`. `printf()` has no concept of `std::string`.

Comment: `wantedString.c_str()` is what you want to give to `printf()`.

Comment: Just don't use printf: `std::cout << "\x1B[92m" << wantedString << "\033[0m"`

Comment: Enabling [compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/GTd89dc3h) should have alerted you to the problem.

Comment: Why are you using both `\x1B` and `\033`?  Do you enjoy tormenting maintainers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `printf` you need a c-style string. Use `wantedString.c_str()`.

Answer (score 2):

`Printf()` is a C function, accessible to C++ only for legacy code compatibility.  But it is not recommended to be used in C++.

The problem you have is that  you are passing a `string` object to it, which is something `printf()` is uncapable of printing.  There's no relationship from a `string` C++ object to a `char *` pointer.

But you are lucky.  There's a method in `string`  (`string::c_str()`) that you can use, as in

```
 printf("\x1B[92m%s\033[0m", wantedString.c_str());
```

---

Anyway, it is better (and everybody will recommend you) to use the `<iostream>` C++ package, which is richer than `stdio` and extensible (you can overload the iostream methods to support your own data types, and that is not possible to do with `printf()` and friends)